# cordova: Control the app remotely?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

How can i remotely access an ionic app i built?
For some reason i want to access my app to get it's local data using my desktop or my sql server?

I want to make sure ill get all the data i do from my app, i did have an upload service where it uploads all the data i need, but in some cases i wan't my desktop/server to access the app remotely and get the data i need.

Is there a way to remotely access an ionic app?

Thanks in advance! I'm using ionic 1 framework, angularJS 1 and php for the server scripts.

Comment: Use Selenium - Web Browser Automation.

Comment: Thanks reading its documentation.